# Text overflowing in HTML checkbox button

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap, button, checkbox

I am trying to add text to my checkbox and want to wrap the words. However, it's coming in one single line. I want to make sure the content fits in the box and increase the height of the box.

[image]

The icon of the checkbox should appear after we have selected, like the one in far left where it says "Cakes ..."

Here is my code:

```css
.searchable-container {
  margin: 20px 0 0 20px
}

.searchable-container label.btn-default.active {
  background-color: #007ba7;
  color: #FFF
}

.searchable-container label.btn-default {
  width: 120%;
  border: 1px solid #efefef;
  margin: 5px;
  box-shadow: 5px 8px 8px 0 #ccc;
}

.searchable-container label .bizcontent {
  width: 100%;
}

.searchable-container {
  word-wrap: break-word;
}

.searchable-container .btn-group {
  width: 120%
}

.searchable-container .btn span.glyphicon {
  opacity: 0;
}

.searchable-container .btn.active span.glyphicon {
  opacity: 1;
}
```

```html
<link href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.3.1/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />

<div class="container">
  <div class="row">
    <div class="form-group">
      <div class="searchable-container">
        <div class="items col-xs-5 col-sm-5 col-md-3 col-lg-3 ">
          <div class="info-block block-info clearfix">

            <div data-toggle="buttons" class="btn-group bizmoduleselect">
              <label class="btn btn-default">
                                <div class="bizcontent">
                                    <input type="checkbox" name="var_id[]" autocomplete="off" value=""> Cakes, Return Gifts 
                                    <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-ok glyphicon-lg"> </span>
                                    
                                </div>
                            </label>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
        <div class="items col-xs-5 col-sm-5 col-md-3 col-lg-3 col-xs-offset-1">
          <div class="info-block block-info clearfix">

            <div data-toggle="buttons" class="btn-group bizmoduleselect">
              <label class="btn btn-default" style="white-space: normal;"> 
                                <div class="bizcontent">
                                    <input type="checkbox" name="var_id[]" autocomplete="off" value=""> Entertainment Magic Show, Games, Puppet Show
                                    <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-ok glyphicon-lg"> </span>
                                   
                                </div>
                            </label>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
        <div class="items col-xs-5 col-sm-5 col-md-3 col-lg-3 col-xs-offset-1">
          <div class="info-block block-info clearfix">

            <div data-toggle="buttons" class="btn-group bizmoduleselect">
              <label class="btn btn-default">
                                <div class="bizcontent">
                                    <input type="checkbox" name="var_id[]" autocomplete="off" value="">Decoration <br> Ballons, Flowers and any other requirements
                                    <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-ok glyphicon-lg"> </span>
                                    
                                </div>
                            </label>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>

  <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
  <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/popper.js/1.14.7/umd/popper.min.js"></script>
  <script src="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.3.1/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: I hate to say this but you weren't helpful either.

Comment: @Alexander That code snippet *doesn't contain any irrelevant code*. You should refrain from posting such comments if you have no idea about the subject matter. **The code posted in this question is, in fact, a good MVCE**.

Comment: @R Prasad 
Can you be specific about what is needed?
Your question consists of two questions internally, Correct me If I am wrong.

Comment: After enabling bootstrap in your snippet, the overflow does not appear to be a problem, just the icon